# How to use Azure File Service list_share() method in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, azure, azure-storage

I want to list the directories and files of a share on Azure Storage account.

Code:

```
file_service = FileService(account_name="xxx",account_key="***")
   lst = file_service.list_directories_and_files('metrics')
   for i in lst:
       print(i)
```

result:
   `<azure.storage.file.models.Directory object at 0x000001DF30FF3278>`

How can I access the data of this object?

The documentation says that the return of this method is a generator.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I access the data of this object?

Taking a look at the documentation here for this object: https://azure-storage.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_modules/azure/storage/file/models.html#Directory, you can print the properties of this object.

For example,

```
file_service = FileService(account_name="xxx",account_key="***")
   lst = file_service.list_directories_and_files('metrics')
   for i in lst:
       print(i.name)
```

It should print the name of directory or file.

Complete documentation can be found here: https://azure-storage.readthedocs.io/en/latest/.